In-App update error ERROR_APP_NOT_OWNED even my versionCode and versionName is lower from current app from playstrore
I've published an app in playstore, and then i want to make in upp update/version check for current app version and updated version from playstore like this
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        final String log = "packageName :" + appUpdateInfo.packageName() + ", " + "availableVersionCode :" + appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode() + ", " + "updateAvailability :" + appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() + ", " + "installStatus :" + appUpdateInfo.installStatus();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable(log));

        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable("On Updating"));
            update();
        } else {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable("Success but Update Unavailable " + log));
            permCheck();
        }
    });

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        final String log = "Update Failure " + e.getMessage();
        final String log2 = "Update Failure " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable(log + " " + log2));
        permCheck();
    });

This is my gradle file
android {

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(***)
        storePassword '***'
        keyAlias '***'
        keyPassword '***'
    }
}
compileSdk = 34
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
flavorDimensions "2.1.6"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "id.***.android"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 2405141
    versionName "2.1.6"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"APP NAME NEW"]
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"APP NAME.Debug"]
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def appName = "APP NAME"
                def fileName = appName + "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + variant.buildType.name + ".apk"
                output.outputFileName = fileName
            }
        }
    }
}

productFlavors {
    def addActivityLabelSuffix = { placeholders, suffix ->
        def appName = placeholders.get("APP NAME")
        placeholders.put("APP NAME", appName + suffix)
    }
    dev {
        applicationId "APP NAME.dev"
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "APP NAME.dev"
        addActivityLabelSuffix getManifestPlaceholders(), ".Dev"
    }

    staging {
        applicationId "APP NAME.stg"
        addActivityLabelSuffix getManifestPlaceholders(), ".Staging"
    }

    production {
        applicationId "APP NAME.new"
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
namespace 'APPNAME'
}

but the error is
-10: Install Error(-10): The app is not owned by any user on this device. An app is "owned" if it has been acquired from Play. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode#ERROR_APP_NOT_OWNED)
My launched app version code is 2405221(2.1.9) which bigger from my current versionCode and versionName that i've added before

Where did you install the apk from, via play store (testing or production) ? or via android studio / adb ? If you didn't install it from the google play store you may face this error.

@MohamedShannan i install it direct from android studio for testing if there's a newest version in playstore, so i made a lower versionCode and versionName for detect it
